# Modify the DateField format shown on ModelAdmin list_display

Tags: django, datetime, django-models, format, django-admin

On my ModelAdmin I'm able to see task_date DateField using the format I desire (which is # format='%Y-%m-%d'). However, when using `list_display('task_date')`, the same DateField is shown in another format. How can I specify the format that list_display needs to use for DateFields?

On models.py

```
class StaffTimeSheet(models.Model):

    time_sheet_owner = models.ForeignKey("Staff", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date') # format='%Y-%m-%d'        
    task_belongs_to_order = models.ManyToManyField("Order", related_name = 'order_present_in_timesheet_of')
    task_start_time = models.TimeField()
    task_end_time = models.TimeField()
    service_category = models.ManyToManyField("ServiceCategory", related_name = 'service_category_present_in_timesheet_of')
    task_description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.time_sheet_owner) + " / " + str(self.task_date) + " / " + str(self.task_start_time)
```

On admin.py

```
class StaffTimeSheetModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
 #determines size of input text box
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.CharField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'size':'50'})},
        models.TextField: {'widget': Textarea(attrs={'rows':2, 'cols':50})},
    }

    fields = ['time_sheet_owner','task_date','task_belongs_to_order','task_start_time','task_end_time','service_category','task_description']

    def task_belongs_to_project_order (self,staff_time_sheet_obj):
        return "\n".join([str(order.order_project.project_number) + "-" + str(order.order_number) for order in staff_time_sheet_obj.task_belongs_to_order.all()])

    # TODO enforce a date format year-month-day
    list_display = ('time_sheet_owner','task_date','task_belongs_to_project_order','task_start_time','task_end_time','task_description')

    search_fields = ['task_date','task_description','task_belongs_to_order__order_number','task_belongs_to_order__order_project__project_number'] # TODO add task_belongs_to_project_order
    list_filter = ('time_sheet_owner','task_date',)


admin.site.register(StaffTimeSheet, StaffTimeSheetModelAdmin)
```

This is how the DateField looks when creating a new StaffTimeSheet object

[image: date filed format]

This is the list of created StaffTimeSheet objects in which I want to modify the format of the task_date DateField

[image: date filed format list_display]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve this problem I had to do 2 things.

1. Write a funcion inside class StaffTimeSheetModelAdmin as suggested by @Clifton Avil D'Souza
2. Convert time to my desired format

In order to do step 2, I created a helper funcion called day_hour_format_converter in whch I had to perform UTC to local time convertion because by default the time stored in the database was in UTC and I was displaying wrong hour values

models.py was not modified. This is my updated code:

On admin.py

```
from django.utils.timezone import now, localtime

def day_hour_format_converter(date_time_UTC):
    local_time = localtime(date_time_UTC)
    return str(local_time.year) +'-'+ str(local_time.month) +'-'+ str(local_time.day) + ' , ' + str(local_time.hour) +':'+ str(local_time.minute) 

class StaffTimeSheetModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    formfield_overrides = {
        models.CharField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'size':'50'})},
        models.TextField: {'widget': Textarea(attrs={'rows':2, 'cols':50})},
    }

    def task_belongs_to_project_order (self,staff_time_sheet_obj):
        return "\n".join([str(order.order_project.project_number) + "-" + str(order.order_number) for order in staff_time_sheet_obj.task_belongs_to_order.all()])

    def start_time(self, staff_time_sheet_obj):
      if staff_time_sheet_obj.task_start_time:
        return day_hour_format_converter(staff_time_sheet_obj.task_start_time)

    def end_time(self, staff_time_sheet_obj):
      if staff_time_sheet_obj.task_end_time:
        return day_hour_format_converter(staff_time_sheet_obj.task_end_time)


    list_display = ('time_sheet_owner','task_belongs_to_project_order','start_time','end_time','task_description')
    search_fields = ['task_start_time','task_description','task_belongs_to_order__order_number','task_belongs_to_order__order_project__project_number']  #TODO be able to look for "project-order" as a monolitic expression
    list_filter = ('time_sheet_owner','task_start_time')
```

Answer (score 0):

write a function in that admin.py inside class `StaffTimeSheetModelAdmin`

```
    def custom_date_format(self, obj):
      if obj.task_date:
        return "your formatting logic here"
      return ''
```

in `list_display` add `custom_date_format`

Comment: Thank you very much! This gave me a good clue, even though it is not the full solution